# ¿Cómo evaluó el tiempo de respuesta de un dropdown en angular 5?

Tags: angular5, test, rendimiento

estoy utilizando Angular 5 y tengo un dropdown que se demoraba mucho en responder, pero ahora pude optimizarlo con cierta librería, pero requiero hacer testing de ello.
Que herramienta me recomiendan para medir el tiempo de respuesta?, se trata de pruebas de rendimiento o son otras?

Algún tutorial que me recomienden?

Saludos

Comment: No estoy seguro pero puedes probar con Lighthouse, en la parte de rendering o painting.